# struggle/battle/fight - which one fits the context better?

Tags: word-choice

> The elevator doors opened to reveal Jamal and the gunman in a fierce
> struggle/battle/fight for the gunman's machine gun.

Imagine that both men are holding onto the machine gun and are trying with force to pull it out of each others hands.

Which one of "struggle", "battle" or "fight" would fit the context better?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with 'struggle', mostly because that (at least to me) encompasses this smaller part of a larger action better. The two may be in a fight more generally but this smaller part of trying to gain physical control of the gun is a more discrete portion.